# Converse of DIC

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

[image]

I am looking to prove the converse of the *Divisibility of Integer Combination*.

I know how to prove the contrapositive of this statement but not the converse ... any help?

Below is my attempt at the solution

[image]

Comment: Someone named this statement? Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In particular 'a' would divide bx+cy for x=0 y=1

Comment: Thanks ... but for the actual proof, is it valid for me to only showcase 'one' instance of x and y in which the statement is true

What I mean to say is that the proof involves a universal quantifier, so is the strategy of using a fixed value for x and y valid?

Comment: Yes, it is enough to show a single case.

Comment: Exactly my point, I know from class that with an existential quantifier showing one case is enough, but for a universal case should I not show that for all x and y the statement holds?

Extremely sorry for being a total noob in this

Comment: You need to show that a|b. There is no variable 'x' involved. I am not able to understand your doubt! It is given that a|(bx+cy) for all x,y$\in Z$. You need to show a|b, where is the problem?

Comment: oh, now I understand. Sorry for making you explain it twice, just had to think it over.

Thank you for the help

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Posted my solution ... correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative suggestion.
Suppose you want to disprove that converse statement then you must show that its negation is true. Thus,

$\exists a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}(\forall x,y\in \mathbb{Z}, a|(bx+cy) \wedge(a\nmid b \vee a\nmid c))$

That is, find $a, b,c$ integers such that no matter the pairs you pick for integers $x$ and $y$, $a$ divides $bx+cy$. This will only hold if you chose both $b$ and $c$ to be some multiples of $a$. But notice if $b$ and $c$ are multiples of $a$, then $a$ divides $b$ and $a$ divides $c$. This makes the conclusion part of that negative statement false. Thus, there are no such $a,b,c$ that satisfy the statement so we are unable to disprove the converse statement.